A cop asked for my social security number after filing a missing child report (my child returned) and I was told it is procedure, how true is this?
I made a missing child report 10-23-24 (my child as returned by the way) but the cop asked for my social security number (and my daughters) and told me that was the procedure. How true is that, because after giving my SSN and they left I felt I wasn’t supposed to be asked that? Please correct me if I’m wrong.

This is very normal.

The expectation there there is only one country and one set of laws on this planet makes me believe you are talking about the United States? Please add a country tag, if it's a federation, maybe the name of the federal state. Where I live, I would have needed to go home and find my hardcopy printout from 25 years ago, because nobody knows their SSN. I assume it's different where you live.

this site encourages answers from other jurisdictions.

@bdb484 There is a difference to being normal and being illegal and/or abusing something.  And the SSN is not meant to be used as a de-facto ID.  Especially as knowing an SSN is a gateway for identity theft.  And there are many videos of cops online saying "this is the procedure" even when the truth is that their activities are not legal.

@PeterM So you don't give them your SSN due risk of identity theft, and you get arrested, taken to jail and fingerprinted because you have a similar name to somebody with warrants. Works both ways.

@user71659 At which time you have an open and shut case of the cops abusing your civil liberties, and you can expect a big payday in your future.  Cops can't legally arrest you "just because"

@nvoigt There is no other country in the world, so far as I know, that calls its national identity number a "Social Security number" which is a unique accident of history in the United States.

@PeterM Cops can arrest you in a case of mistaken identity until they are overwhelmingly convinced of their mistake and refuse to fix it. Unless they do it to you several times in row, law enforcement almost never has any liability in that situation and you've been arrested and had your life massively disrupted. It is almost never illegal for law enforcement to ask for SSNs in connection with an ongoing criminal or missing persons investigation.

@nvoigt In the US, your SSN is often your driver's license number, and it's used in many other contexts like banking and insurance, so most adults know their number (or they carry the card and can give it to the cop). It's not supposed to be a universal ID number, but it ends up acting like it.

@Barmar Bush signed a federal law in 2004 about prohibiting using SSNs for drivers license IDs.  Most states have been slowly confirming to it.

@ohwilleke You need to preface your comment with "good cops", because bad cops can and will arrest people for whatever put their nose out of joint.  Same as for respecting activities protected under the constitution.  The good cops respect them, they bad cops will go out of they way to illegally harass people.

@PeterM I'm in MA, we've had the ability to opt out of using SSN for driver's license for a long time. I don't know how many take advantage of this, but I've been doing it since long before 2004.

@PeterM The Real ID Act, however, while not actually putting SSNs on driver's licenses, does require verification of citizenship which is usually done with a federal databased indexed by SSN. There are alternative ways citizenship can be verified, but an SSN is the easiest and usual way to get a Real ID driver's license or state ID which is necessary to fly on even domestic commercial airline flights. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_ID_Act

@PeterM Re good cops v. bad cops. As I note at the end of my answer, if you are dealing with a bad cop, misuse of you or your child's SSN is the least of your worries.

@ohwilleke regarding Real ID: is it?  If I show my passport, don't they verify that with the Department of State?  You wouldn't need a social security number to do that.

@phoog Only 51% of Americans have a passport, and that is even more rare for children.

@ohwilleke I see.  I was questioning "verification of citizenship which is usually done with a federal databased indexed by SSN" but it didn't occur to me that this might be "usual" depending on which documents are presented in the application.  Children do not need Real ID licenses to pass TSA, however; the requirement applies only to those who are 18 or older.

Short Answer

How true is that, because after giving my SSN and they left I felt I
wasn’t supposed to be asked that?

Don't worry about it. This is very normal and there are legitimate reasons for asking.
Long Answer
Court records and child protective services records are often indexed by Social Security number (SSN). This allows law enforcement to confirm that there aren't protective orders, custody decrees, active abuse and neglect cases, death certificates, etc. that they need to be aware of but haven't been informed about by the person making the report (who may not even be aware of them).
Names aren't nearly as good for indexing records because there are common given names, some ethnicities have a few very common surnames, and there are many variant spellings of names. Also, sometimes when a child has parents or caretaking relatives with different surnames the child will go by different surnames at different times (e.g., that was the experience of Vice President-elect J.D. Vance, who is a man who has gone by several surnames during his life).
SSNs can also be used to confirm that you are who you say you are and not someone trying to sow mischief, and assists in prosecuting someone for making a false report if you misidentify yourself.
The wariness comes from sometimes over the top efforts of mostly divorced or never married co-parents (and sometimes other relatives in caretaker roles or supporting other co-parent family members) to manipulate law enforcement and child protection officials for malicious reasons to harass their exs and to gain advantage in child custody related cases (sometimes hoping for a "where's there's smoke, there's fire" reaction from a family court judge or magistrate or social worker or child and family investigator). This kind of outright manipulation and fraud of authorities related to children isn't all that common, but when you have tens of millions of children in this situation and these kinds of tactics come up in maybe 2-3% of cases, these proxy wars between parents can overwhelm legitimate missing person report cases in almost any law enforcement agency.
I don't do a lot of chid custody work, so I haven't seen it often, but talking to people who do and seeing media reports, I'm well aware that it happens.
Police especially don't want to have egg on their faces after issuing high profile Amber Alert or other high profile announcements to the general public without confirming that the case is legitimate first.
It is almost never illegal for law enforcement to ask for (and receive and use) SSNs in connection with an ongoing criminal or missing persons investigation.
The main problem with this requirement is that there are something on the order of ten million undocumented immigrants in the United States, many of whom are children or have U.S. born children who are U.S. citizens and sometimes something happens to them that law enforcement needs to intervene to help deal with. And, if a parent and/or child doesn't have an SSN and that prevents an investigation from going forward, that child who may be in a dangerous situation may suffer.
Also, not ever resident of the United States has a Social Security number (it is not required unless it is needed for some particular tax related purpose), although the requirement that Social Security numbers be provided on tax returns to claim the child tax credit and other tax benefits related to dependent children has dramatically reduced the number of children who do not have an SSN.
If you already have and know your SSN and your child's SSN, there is really no harm in sharing this information with law enforcement, and if a report containing the SSNs is disclosed to the public or third-parties without a need to know, the SSNs are usually redacted before the report is disclosed.
As a practical matter, there is only so much you can do to keep an SSN private. Employers need it. Tax authorities need it. People whom you do independent contractor work need it. Most welfare benefit agencies need it. Lenders who want to do credit checks before extending you credit, or who work with credit reporting agencies, need it. Banks and financial institutions need it. Real estate closing firms need it. Courts in divorces and child related lawsuits need it. Coroners need it. The Social Security program needs it. Jails and prisons need it. It is sometimes needed for state IDs. Lawyers distributing inheritances and trust funds need it. The military needs it for veteran's benefits. This isn't information that can be kept ultra-top secret, and if you contact law enforcement first you can be pretty confident that they are legitimate (although, of course, there is always that ultra-rare super sophisticated scammer to let you know that no amount of caution is perfect protection from fraud). Most of the people you have to give your SSN to by law are less trustworthy than law enforcement officers are in this context.
In short, don't worry about being asked for you or your child's SSN. When your child is missing, this isn't something you should be worried about when talking to bona fide law enforcement officers.
If indeed you are unfortunate enough to be dealing with a bad cop who is willing to harm you or your child, misuse of your SSN or your child's SSN is the least of your worries. (I considered linking to some examples of that, but thought better of that idea. Read media stories if you can't imagine the possibilities.)

It should be mentioned that no all US residents have SSN.  Also, that the SS Administration will not guarantee that the same SSN might be assigned to more than one person, or that one person might obtain multiple SSNs. Use of SSN for identification is full of flaws.   I lost my SS Card, but as I remember,  bold words on the bottom of the card said NOT FOR IDENTIFICATION.

@SvTarwathie Any yet, notwithstanding these best intentions and flaws, SSNs are pervasively used by courts, child protective services, credit reporting agencies, financial firms, state driver's license bureaus, the military, and more. This is the reality and it isn't a terribly scary one. The main alternative is to use names which have a greater probability of being assigned to more than one person, and it is more likely that someone has more than one name. Institutions use SSNs because it is better than the alternatives in wide use. In an ideal world we'd come up with something better.

At least two US presidents have had their names changed in childhood for similar reasons, including Leslie Lynch King Jr. (later Gerald Rudolph Ford Jr.) and William Jefferson Blythe III (later William Jefferson Clinton).

@phoog Good catch!
